# D3 Dimple - group small data series in "others" category

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I have a pie chart made in dimple, however the there is large amount of extremely small sections that makes the graph unappealing. Is there a d3 or dimple function that will allow me to group this uninteresting data in a single category?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

without seeing your code and data it is hard to provide a concrete example that matches exactly what you are doing.  this can be done before using d3 or dimple by filtering and reducing your values in a few lines of code.  Say your items have a label and a value and are in an array called "all_items".  You will need to set a threshold value.

```
const threshold = 100;
big_items = all_items.filter(item => item.value > threshold);
small_items = all_items.filter(item => item.value <= threshold);
collected_value = { 
    label: `other - ${small_items.length} items`,
    value: small_items.reduce((accumulator, item) => accumulator + item.value, 0)
}
big_items.push(collected_value);
```

then you can create your chart using the big_items array.  This doesn't automatically decide what threshold to use and do the work, which you might be looking for.